# Поиск в массиве чисел, повторяющихся определенное количество раз

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Дан массив из 25 целых чисел в диапазоне [-3..5]. Найти и записать в новый массив только те элементы, которые повторяются 3 раза (не меньше и не больше 3). Определить есть ли в полученном массиве 0(ноль). Вот пример того что делаю, помогите эту простыню сократить и что бы заработало

```
int tempEl, tempIn;
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    tempEl = arr[i];
    tempIn = i;
    for (j = i + 1; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] < tempEl)
        {
            tempIn = j;
            tempEl = arr[j];
        }
    }
    arr[tempIn] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = tempEl;
}
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    cout << arr[i] << "  ";
}
cout << endl;
int arr_2[SIZE]{};
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1] && arr[i] == arr[i - 1] && 
    arr[i] != arr[i + 2] && arr[i] != arr[i - 2])
    {
        arr_2[count++] = arr[i];
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    cout << arr_2[i] << "  ";
}
cout << endl;
int key = 0;
int indKey = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (arr_2[i] == key)
    {
        indKey = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (indKey != -1)
{
    cout << "The digit " << key << " is present in this array." << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "The digit " << key << " is not found." << endl;
}
system("pause");
```

}

Нельзя использовать функции и вектора.

Answer (score 5):

Вот... Мне кажется, что при указанных ограничениях [так](https://ideone.com/FHQR5y) попроще.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int a[25];

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    // Заполнение массива
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
    {
        cout << (a[i] = rand()%9-3) << "  ";
    }
    cout << "\n\n";

    // Вспомогательный массив
    int count[9] = { 0 };

    // Подсчет чисел
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
        count[a[i]+3]++;

    // Выборка только троек
    for(int i = -3; i <=5; ++i)
        if (count[i+3] == 3)
        {
            // Можетее записывать в новый массив;
            // я просто вывожу в консоль
            cout << i << "  ";
        }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Ну, проверить на ноль - думаю, это настолько тривиально, что вы напишете сами? :)

Comment: Кажется я повторил этот код

Comment: Я бы делал `int _count[9] = { 0 }, *count = _count + 3;` и тогда бы не понадобилось прибавлять тройку тут: `count[a[i]+3]++;`.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну да, согласен, вполне приличная идиома :)

Answer (score 3):

```
const int low = -3, up = 5, sz = 25, mark_size = up - low + 1;
int arr[sz];
for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
    std::cin >> arr[i]; 
    arr[i] %= up + 1;
}

int m[mark_size] = {0}, new_arr[mark_size];
for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
    ++m[arr[i] - low];
}
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < mark_size; ++i) {        
    cout << low + i << "  :    " << m[i]  << " pieces\n";
    if (m[i] == 3)
        new_arr[j++] = low + i;
}
```

Для общего случая, если диапазон меньше размера исходного массива

Answer (score 2):

> Найти и записать в новый массив только те элементы, которые
>   повторяются 3 раза (не меньше и не больше 3)

Это означает, что результирующий массив должен содержать именно значения из исходного массива, которые в исходном массиве присутствуют в 3-х экземплярах.

Результирующий массив может содержать не больше, чем `25 / 3` (где `25` - это число элементов в исходном массиве согласно описанию задания), то есть максимум `8` элементов. Результирующий массив может быть полностью заполнен только в том случае, когда каждое значение исходного массива (за исключением одного) будет встречаться в нем ровно 3 раза.

Алгоритм может быть таким. Сначала для очередного элемента исходного массива мы смотрим, присутствует ли он уже ранее в исходном массиве, чтобы избежать лишних итераций в исходном массиве. Если присутствует, то есть уже был ранее подсчитан, то мы переходим к следующему элементу исходного массива. В противном случае начинаем подсчитывать, сколько раз данный элемент встречается в исходном массиве. Если ровно 3 раза, то записываем данный элемент в результирующий массив и увеличиваем текущую длину результирующего массива на 1.

Данный подход не зависит от диапазона значений исходного массива.

Ниже представлена соответствующая демонстрационная программа.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 25;
    const int LOWER_VALUE = -3, UPPER_VALUE = 5;
    const int MAX_RANGE = UPPER_VALUE - LOWER_VALUE + 1;
    const size_t OCCURENCES = 3;

    int source[N];
    int result[std::min( N / OCCURENCES, size_t( MAX_RANGE ) )] = {};
    //  or just
    //  int result[N / OCCURENCES] = {};

    //  fill source with random numbers
    std::srand( std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( auto &x : source )
    {
        x = std::rand() % MAX_RANGE - std::abs( LOWER_VALUE );
    }

    //  output source on console
    std::cout << "source: ";
    for ( const auto &x : source ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    //  trying to form result
    size_t n = 0;   //  n - current number of elements in result

    for ( size_t i = 0; i + OCCURENCES - 1 < N; i++ )
    {
        //  check whether the element source[i] was already processed
        size_t j = 0;
        while ( j < i && source[j] != source[i] ) j++;

        if ( j == i )
        {
            //  source[i] is not present in result
            size_t count = 1;
            for ( size_t k = i + 1; k < N; ++k )
            {
                if ( source[k] == source[i] ) ++count;
            }

            if ( count == OCCURENCES ) result[n++] = source[i];
        }
    }

    //  output result on console
    std::cout << "result: ";
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) std::cout << result[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    //  check whether 0 is present in result
    bool present = false;
    const int value = 0;
    for ( size_t i = 0; not present && i < n; i++ )
    {
        present = result[i] == value;
    }

    std::cout << value << " is " << ( present ? "" : "not" )
              << " present in the result array.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть, к примеру, следующим образом:

```
source: -1 4 0 2 3 1 -3 2 1 5 5 -3 -3 2 -3 5 1 0 -3 -3 4 -2 0 4 4 
result: 0 2 1 5 
0 is  present in the result array.
```